# Image to byte array inconsistent

Tags: java, image, tcp

I'm currently trying to convert a JPEG image from the local java project directory to a byte array to send over a tcp connection.

This is currently how I'm converting my file to a byte array:

```
BufferedImage imageBuff = ImageIO.read(new File("res/image.jpg"));
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
ImageIO.write(imageBuff, "JPEG", baos);
byte[] res = baos.toByteArray();
System.out.println(baos.toByteArray());
```

I can't seem to find a solid answer as to why this is happening, but every-time I convert it the data is not consistent:

System output:

```
[B@23f23303
[B@6299504b
[B@417f69df
```

What exactly is the byte array supposed to look like? It's clearly not working on the other side of the TCP connection for me unfortunately. I would think the output would have the same output each time it tries to convert it, no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling `toString` on a `byte[]`. Arrays don't override `toString()`, so you're seeing the [implementation in `Object`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString%28%29):

> The toString method for class Object returns a string consisting of the name of the class of which the object is an instance, the at-sign character `@', and the unsigned hexadecimal representation of the hash code of the object. In other words, this method returns a string equal to the value of:
>
> ```
> getClass().getName() + '@' + Integer.toHexString(hashCode())
> ```

So in other words, that has nothing to do with the data within the byte array. Use [`Arrays.toString(byte[])`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString%28byte%5B%5D%29) to get a string representation which actually looks reasonable - although you may find a hex conversion easier to read.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation! Definitely makes sense, what I was doing and why it was different each time.

Answer (score 0):

`[B@23f23303` is the String representation of the array object, not the content of the array.

You can use `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(baos.toByteArray()));`

Answer (score 0):

You're printing out information on the array itself (specifically, the array type `[B` for `byte[]`, and then the pointer to the array contents). You probably want to print `Arrays.toString(res)`.